# NPE when getting Robolectric ShadowApplication with Volley and Dagger

Tags: android, robolectric, dagger, android-volley

In my Android application I have set up Volley.

Robolectric.application is initialized and all other tests runs smoothly.
I get this error when trying to get mocked HTTP response.

This is my test:

```
@RunWith(MyRobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class ApiTests {

    @Inject
    protected Api api;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        ObjectGraph.create(new AndroidModule(Robolectric.application), new TestApplicationModule()).inject(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldGetErrorList() throws Exception {
        Project project = new Project("test", "test", "test", DateTime.now());
        addPendingProjectsErrorsResponse("response.json"); //adding response to FakeHttpLayer

        api.getProjectErrors(project, new Listener<ProjectErrors>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(ProjectErrors response) {
                    assertNotNull(response);
                }
            }, new ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(error);
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

This is error I get:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.getMainLooper(ShadowLooper.java:59)
    at android.os.Looper.getMainLooper(Looper.java)
    at org.robolectric.Robolectric.getUiThreadScheduler(Robolectric.java:1301)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowSystemClock.now(ShadowSystemClock.java:15)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowSystemClock.uptimeMillis(ShadowSystemClock.java:25)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowSystemClock.elapsedRealtime(ShadowSystemClock.java:30)
    at android.os.SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(SystemClock.java)
    at com.android.volley.VolleyLog$MarkerLog.add(VolleyLog.java:114)
    at com.android.volley.Request.addMarker(Request.java:174)
    at com.android.volley.CacheDispatcher.run(CacheDispatcher.java:92)
```

Answer (score -2):

I had same error and avoid it by using my own (and ugly) SystemClock shadow.

shadow class:

```
@Implements(value = SystemClock.class, callThroughByDefault = true)
public static class MyShadowSystemClock {
    public static long elapsedRealtime() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

test code:

```
@Test
@Config(shadows = { MyShadowSystemClock.class, ... })
public void myTest() {
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Another workaround would be to disable Volley logging by calling

```
VolleyLog.DEBUG = false;
```

in your setUp method.